# PostMessage interferes with user input

Tags: autoit, jna, user32

I'm trying to send key stroke to an external application in java using jna.

It sends VK_DOWN key, also that application has a shortcut for ctrl+down which makes something very different. My application sends around ~15 down key with 1 sec in between, and if user happens to click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> during it while working on a different window, it breaks the application(treats it as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>).

I checked the keyboard messages via Spy++, compared mine with AutoIt, they are exactly same messages.

`ControlSend("window_title", "", "", "{DOWN}")`

This AutoIt code works perfect, even if I click ctrl when window is active or inactive, it does not interfere with down key.
My code on the other hand:

```
    User32.INSTANCE.PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, wparam, lparamDown);
    User32.INSTANCE.PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, wparam, lparamUp);
```

has exactly same messages, but it doesn't work.

I tried sending control up before sending down key but to no avail.

Spy++ output:

```
<14335> 00011456 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_DOWN cRepeat:1 ScanCode:50 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<14336> 00011456 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_DOWN cRepeat:1 ScanCode:50 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

My ctrl clicks are not even on target application so why does it treat it as such? Should I use a hook?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I need to send input to background/non focused windows. SendInput does not do that afaik